# Socket connection succeeds even with wrong/null URL

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I am running a test using the Java socket class, but somehow my socket.connect ALWAYS connects successfully to something, even if my url variable is null or incorrect. Does anyone know why?

```
package ping_run_send;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*
import java.security.cert.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class tcpping {
    private String url, status;
    private Date timestamp;
    private long rtime;
    
    tcpping(String input_url){
        this.url = input_url;
    }
    void ping() {
        try{
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("my proxy", 80));
            Socket socket = new Socket(proxy);
            long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(url, 80),2000);
            long tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
            rtime =  tEnd-tStart;
            timestamp = new Date(tStart);
            
            InputStream sIn = socket.getInputStream();
            
            if (sIn != null) {
                status = "normal";
                socket.close();
            }else {
                status = "error";
            }
        } catch(final MalformedURLException e){
            status = "error";
        } catch(IOException e){
            status = "error";
        }
    }
    Long get_rtime() {
        return rtime;
    }
    Date get_timestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    String get_status() {
        return status;
    }
    
}
```

I also tried changing the if statement from isConnected() to

```
            InputStream sIn = socket.getInputStream();
            if (sIn != null) {
                status = "normal";
                socket.close();
            }else {
                status = "error";
            }
```

But nothing seems to be have changed on its ability to detect connection error.

my testing file:

```
package ping_run_send;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import ping_run_send.httpping;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        String url = "http://google.com";
        //urls like "",http://gowegwgwoJOIJOI03OINEPJPogle.#(*%" all works somehow
        
        tcpping testTcp = new tcpping(url);
        testTcp.ping();
        System.out.println("tcp ping:");
        System.out.println(testTcp.get_rtime());
        System.out.println(testTcp.get_timestamp());
        System.out.println(testTcp.get_status());
        

        
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you checking the connection was successful? You should log the exceptions you catch, currently you have no way of knowing what is going wrong

Comment: i use the status variable as a flag. I do an if statement to check if my connection was successful or not. I'm not getting any errors though. My status is always set to "normal" somehow...

Comment: Can you show the code you use for the if statement?

Comment: How do you know it's always connecting? Instead of saying 'status = "error"', you probably want to display something with System.out.println("error"), so you know if there's an error. Better yet, though, maybe you're stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: @JWoodchuck I just need to check once per run, this ping() method is called every 5 minute by a server runner to check a url for the tcp layer. I meant to let it work like how an ICMP ping test would.

Comment: @Joni If there were IOExceptions or URL issues, my exceptions will catch it. I never have any exception though. On top of the exceptions I use an if statement (as shown above in the code) to check if the connection is successful.

Comment: Can you make a short but complete program that shows the problem you're having? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Right now it's really hard to guess what might be going wrong because the code is incomplete. In particular, if URL is null, InetSocketAddress will throw an "illegal argument exception" which you're not catching.

Comment: @Joni i have updated the code to include the entire class.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're experiencing: `new tcpping(null).ping()` fails by throwing an IllegalArgumentException, and `new tcpping("~invalid~").ping()` fails by throwing an InternalError. I must assume you are running the program in some different way. Please post a **complete** program that shows the problem

Comment: the rest is just the main.java file, i have updated that. are you using a proxy? i think the issue is my socket.connect somehow checks the connection to the proxy instead of to the url itself. i am using a corporate proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It is connecting to the Proxy. When you specify a Proxy the connection is made to the Proxy and the Proxy itself handles the connections to the real endpoint.

Comment: So if I specify the proxy, my what i specify in my socket.connect(address) doesn't matter anymore?

Comment: Depends on the implementation, but generally that is right. The client initiating the connect() wouldn't even perform a DNS lookup; instead just pass what it knows about the remote end to the proxy and ask it to manage all the hard work. The client implementation is your code so you are free to do what you want here, though.

Comment: sry im a bit confused, are you saying that it works fine? I get that the actual connection to the server url is done by my proxy, but i still don't get how i can fix the fact that it connects successfully no matter what url i feed it.

Comment: Correct. What you seem to be missing is that the isConnected() method is reporting the status of your socket. Your socket did manage to get the TCP/IP stack to perform the 3-way handshake with your proxy server, so it reports success.

Comment: I later tried    InputStream sIn = socket.getInputStream();
  if (sIn != null) status = normal, but i still get the same result.. it works no matter what i set as my url. Is this because proxy socket is sending my socket actual streams?

Comment: Correct. The getInputStream() is now a stream that reads data from the proxy server.

Comment: is there anything you suggest that could get my socket API to test the entire transport layer from my internal network to the http server rather than just to the proxy?

Comment: The proxy (assuming it is a mature one, like say Squid) already does that very reliably. There is no reason for your code to do so; in fact the huge variety of configurations of the proxy and in the connectivity between the proxy and the server makes this a futile exercise. Maybe you should rethink the use-case you are working on.

If you really, really want to do the test you are describing, create a special "heardbeat" URL at the server and request it from the client. Then process the response you get for a known "good" response to signal all-clear or raise an error flag otherwise.